# JAVASCRIPT looping through a jquery array and adding a class to current item while removing the class from the previous item the next time through

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create somewhat of a tabSelect function in a card game where the player will be able to select 1 of the 5 cards in their hand. I made a highlight class and am adding it to a div containing the card image so the outline changes from blue to light blue. So in the loop the class should be added to the first div, then the second div while removing it from the first div, then the third div while removing it from the second div....etc.

this is what i have tried so far but its not working as intended :

```
selectCard() {
    const $playerOneHand = $('.pOne')
    for (i = 0; i < $playerOneHand.length; i++) {
        if ($($playerOneHand[i - 1]).hasClass('highlight') == true) {
            $($playerOneHand[i - 1]).removeClass('highlight')
        }
        if ($($playerOneHand[i]).hasClass('highlight') == false) {
            $($playerOneHand[i]).addClass('highlight')
            return
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding an `else` before the second `if` (or just replacing the second `if` entirely with `else`)

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the card that's currently highlighted. Increment that index to get the one to highlight in its place.

```js
function selectCard() {
  var index = $(".pOne.highlight").index(".pOne");
  index = (index + 1) % $(".pOne").length; // increment and wrap around
  $(".pOne").removeClass("highlight");
  $(".pOne").eq(index).addClass("highlight");
}

$("#next").click(selectCard);
```

```css
.pOne {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pOne.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pOne highlight">1</div>
<div class="pOne">2</div>
<div class="pOne">3</div>
<div class="pOne">4</div>
<div class="pOne">5</div>

<button id="next">Next Card</button>
```